# How can I find the author of a post in discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

I want to have my bot send a message that says "shut up" whenever my friend sends a message. I don't know where to start. How can I do this?

Comment: Check out the tutorials here:
https://realpython.com/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-python/

Comment: I'm not sure how that helps. It doesn't say anything about what I want, but thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: There is a section about reacting to messages with your bot using the `on_message()` method. The example below checks the message's author. This way you could check if it's your friend and reply to him with the bot.
https://realpython.com/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-python/#responding-to-messages

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to replace "<YOUR FRIEND'S ID>" with your friend's user ID (right-click > Copy ID) {if you cannot see this, enable "Developer Mode" in Discord Advanced Settings}

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id == <YOUR FRIEND'S ID>:
        await message.channel.send("shut up")
    else:
        return
    await client.process_commands(message)
```